# registering Ember.Helper in non ember-cli apps

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How to register `Ember.Helper` without using `ember-cli`

I have a set of helpers that I want to migrate but our application is not ready to be migrated to ember-cli yet.

SOLUTION:
use the registry.

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
  Application.initializer({
    name: 'registerMyHelper',
    initialize: function(registry/*, application*/) {
      registry.register('helper:my-helper', MyHelper);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/writing-helpers/ - will explain in further details, however:

Few ways:

1. Ember.Handlebars.helper is the best way to register helpers. The
   other ways are  versions of it. Ember.Handlebars.helper renders HTML
   with bindings and sync.. You can pass many things into it.
2. Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper is just like
   Ember.Handlebars.helper, but only accept a function as a parameter
   (hence why I use it in the examples)
3. Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper previously delegated to
   Handlebars.registerHelper. Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper no longer
   exists, but Handlebars.registerHelper is still used internally by
   Ember to create all the helpers after the bindings are set up.

Example of a simple and more complex helpers:

```
//Helper to translate a number to words:
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper("skillLevelToWords", function (levelNum) {
  if (levelNum < 3) return "Beginner";
  if (levelNum == 3 || Ember.isEmpty(levelNum)) return "Intermediate";
  if (levelNum > 3) return "Expert";
})

/**
 * Helper to itearte object properties and to print each one with value and key.
  */
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('eachProperty', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";
  var newContext = Ember.get(this, context);
  for(var prop in newContext)
  {
    if (newContext.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      ret = ret + options.fn({property:prop,value:newContext[prop]});
    }
  }
  return ret;
});
```